# Solidity: Error when calling a function of another contract. Error: The constructor should be payable when you send value

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, contract

I am playing around with Solidity and I thought of seeing how a test marketplace would function. However, I seem to have run into an issue which I cant seem to figure out. The code is shabby because I am just trying to figure out how it works on the testnet so please forgive me for that.

Basically, when trying to buy an item using the below function(for which a seller and a product should be created)

```
  function buyItem(uint _no, address[] _sigs, uint _amount) public payable {
    Product storage productIndex = productsArray[_no];
    Seller storage productSeller = sellers[productIndex.oneSeller];
    address buyer = msg.sender;
    address seller = productSeller.sellerAddress;
    uint amount = _amount;
    bytes32 transactionHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(buyer, seller, amount, _sigs));
    txHash.push(transactionHash);

    require(msg.sender != 0);
    require(msg.sender != productSeller.sellerAddress, "Buyer address is same as Seller Address");
    require(amount >= productIndex.price);
    require(productIndex.inStock);

    escrow.createTransaction(buyer, seller, transactionHash, _sigs, amount);
    //address(escrow).transfer(amount);

    productIndex.quantity--;
  }
```

I get this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JnmS.jpg

I am trying to create a transaction entry which is stored in the escrow account. The createTransaction function below takes in all the information and stores it in the escrow account. At least this is what i want it to do. Perhaps I am making some rudimentary error somewhere?

```
escrow.createTransaction(buyer, seller, transactionHash, _sigs, amount);
```

Below is the entire code for both contracts:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

    contract Escrow {

      enum Status{FUNDED, RELEASED}

      struct Transaction {
        address seller;
        address buyer;
        uint value;
        uint lastFunded;
        bytes32 transactionHash;
        address[] signatures;
        Status status;
        mapping(address => bool) isOwner;
        mapping(address => bool) voted;
      }

      mapping(bytes32 => Transaction) public transactions;
      bytes32[] public transactionID;

      modifier onlyOwner(bytes32 _transactionHash) {
        require(msg.sender == transactions[_transactionHash].buyer);
        _;
      }


      function createTransaction(address _buyer, address _seller, bytes32 _transactionHash, address[] _signatures, uint _value) public payable {
        Transaction memory newTransaction = Transaction({
            buyer: _buyer,
            seller: _seller,
            value: _value,
            lastFunded: block.timestamp,
            transactionHash: _transactionHash,
            signatures: _signatures,
            status: Status.FUNDED
          });

        transactions[_transactionHash] = newTransaction;
        transactions[_transactionHash].isOwner[_seller] = true;
        transactions[_transactionHash].isOwner[_buyer] = true;
        transactionID.push(_transactionHash);
      }

      function addOwners(bytes32 _transactionHash) private {
        Transaction storage transaction = transactions[_transactionHash];
        for(uint i = 0; i < transaction.signatures.length; i++) {
          require(transaction.signatures[i] != 0);
          require(!transaction.isOwner[transaction.signatures[i]]);

          transaction.isOwner[transaction.signatures[i]] = true;
        }
      }

      function addFunds(bytes32 _transactionHash) public payable onlyOwner(_transactionHash) {
        uint _value = msg.value;
        require(_value > 0);

        //transactions[_transactionHash].value = transactions[_transactionHash].value.add(_value);
        transactions[_transactionHash].lastFunded = block.timestamp;
      }

      function transferFunds(bytes32 _transactionHash, uint _amount, address _destination) private returns(uint _valueTransferred) {
        Transaction storage transaction = transactions[_transactionHash];

        require(_amount > 0);
        require(_destination != address(0) && transaction.isOwner[_destination]);

        _valueTransferred = _amount;
        _destination.transfer(_amount);
      }

      function confirmHash(bytes32 _transactionHash) public view {
        require(_transactionHash != 0);
        bytes32 calculatedHash = getHash(_transactionHash);

        require(_transactionHash == calculatedHash);
      }

      function getHash(bytes32 _transactionHash) internal view returns(bytes32 hash) {
        Transaction storage transaction = transactions[_transactionHash];
        hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(transaction.buyer, transaction.seller, transaction.signatures, transaction.value));
      }

    }

    contract MarketPlace is Escrow{

      Escrow escrow;

    //Has all the information of a particular product

      struct Product {
        string itemName;
        string color;
        string description;
        string warranty;
        string manufacturer;
        uint quantity;
        uint price;
        bool inStock;
        address oneSeller;
      }

    //Has all the information of the seller and the number of products this seller has.

      struct Seller {
        string sellerName;
        address sellerAddress;
        string sellerPhoneNumber;
        string sellerEmail;
        uint noOfProducts;
        mapping(uint => Product) products;
      }


      event AddedSeller(address seller, string sellerName, string sellerPhoneNumber, string sellerEmail);
      event AddedItem(address seller, string itemName, string color, string description, string warranty, string manufacturer, uint price, uint quantity);

    //Array of Seller struct. Can iterate through the number of sellers that have registered and get their information.
    //Array of Product struct. Can iterate through the number of products that are there in the marketplace. Used an array here to retrieve the products to the marketplace to display them to users.
    //Address of the owner of the marketplace contract. Used to deploy it the first time.
    //Addresses of all the sellers.
    //To hold all the paymentIDs
    //msg.sender is associated with the seller information when he/she is asked to fill in the details before adding products to the page.
    //To make sure that the seller is already in the system to avoid duplications.
    //Payment Details are all held here associated with their UIDs as keys

      Seller[] public sellerList;
      Product[] public productsArray;

      address public owner;
      address[] public sellersAdd;

      bytes32[] public txHash;

      mapping(address => Seller) public sellers;
      mapping(address => bool) public isSeller;


    //Constructor function.
      function MarketPlace() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
      }

    //Function to add a seller.
    //Must be a new seller. Hence, seller address should not exist in the isSeller Mapping.
    //New Seller struct variable is created to push to "Seller[] public sellerList"
    //Adding the struct to the mapping of address to struct.
    //Added seller struct to the array of struct.
    //Marked seller address as true to check later to avoid duplications.
    //Added the seller address to the array of addresses that hold all the sellers.

      function addSeller(string _sellerName, string _sellerPhoneNumber, string _sellerEmail) public {
        require(!isSeller[msg.sender]);

        Seller memory newSeller = Seller({
          sellerName: _sellerName,
          sellerAddress: msg.sender,
          sellerPhoneNumber: _sellerPhoneNumber,
          sellerEmail: _sellerEmail,
          noOfProducts: 0
        });

        sellers[msg.sender] = newSeller;
        sellerList.push(newSeller);
        isSeller[msg.sender] = true;
        sellersAdd.push(msg.sender);

        emit AddedSeller(msg.sender, _sellerName, _sellerPhoneNumber, _sellerEmail);
      }

    //Function to add an Item.
    //Must be an existing seller. Therefore we check to see if the address exists as a registered seller.
    //A new product struct is created to be pushed with the product details to "Product[] public productsArray"
    //noOfProducts holds the amount of products each seller has under his/her account. This value increases as more products are added.
    //The new product is added to the mapping using itemNo as mapping key(uint) which is later incremented to make room for next product
    //noOfProducts is now incremented for when the next product is to be entered
    /*Thew new product is also pushed to an array of products call productsArray. I used arrays here as well on top of mappings just so that I could iterate through the values without having to have any knowledge of mapping keys.*/

      function addItem(string _itemName, string _color, string _description, string _warranty, string _manufacturer, uint _price, uint _quantity) public {
        require(isSeller[msg.sender]);

        Product memory newProduct = Product({
          itemName: _itemName,
          color: _color,
          description: _description,
          warranty: _warranty,
          manufacturer: _manufacturer,
          price: _price,
          quantity: _quantity,
          inStock: true,
          oneSeller: msg.sender
        });

        uint itemNo = sellers[msg.sender].noOfProducts;
        sellers[msg.sender].products[itemNo] = newProduct;
        sellers[msg.sender].noOfProducts++;
        productsArray.push(newProduct);
        emit AddedItem(msg.sender, _itemName, _color, _description, _warranty, _manufacturer, _price, _quantity);
      }

    //Function to get sellers count.

      function getSellerCount() public view returns(uint) {
        return sellerList.length;
      }

    //Function to get the products count so we can iterate through all products and display them.

      function getProductCount() public view returns(uint) {
        return productsArray.length;
      }

    /*Function for buying an item. THIS WAS JUST A SIMPLE FUNCTION I MADE TO KIND OF GET AN IDEA HOW IT WOULD WORK.*/

      function buyItem(uint _no, address[] _sigs, uint _amount) public payable {
        Product storage productIndex = productsArray[_no];
        Seller storage productSeller = sellers[productIndex.oneSeller];
        address buyer = msg.sender;
        address seller = productSeller.sellerAddress;
        uint amount = _amount;
        bytes32 transactionHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(buyer, seller, amount, _sigs));
        txHash.push(transactionHash);

        require(msg.sender != 0);
        require(msg.sender != productSeller.sellerAddress, "Buyer address is same as Seller Address");
        require(amount >= productIndex.price);
        require(productIndex.inStock);

        escrow.createTransaction(buyer, seller, transactionHash, _sigs, amount);
        //address(escrow).transfer(amount);

        productIndex.quantity--;
      }
    }
```

Appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never-mind, I figured out the problem. I had to pass the contract address of `Escrow` into the instance variable. There was no reference of any address that was passed so it was reverting:

```
contract MarketPlace is Escrow {
    Escrow escrow;
    constructor(address _escrowContractAddress) public payable {
        owner = msg.sender;

        //This was the missing code.
        escrow = Escrow(_escrowContractAddress);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand from the error message that the constructor must be payable.

```
  function MarketPlace() public PAYABLE {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }
```

Having the contract name has function as constructor is now deprecated according to the debugger. You can use:

```
constructor() public payable {

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I tried making these changes yet the error still persists :(